# Build not visible in itunes connect with xcode 8.2 ios 10

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios10

i have been using Xcode 8.2 to upload my apps to itunes connect.when i upload it from xcode the build gets uploaded successfully.

However when i login to itunes connect, i can see the build in processing in activity section for few seconds,  then the build gets disappear automatically without any error or information.

i have also file a bug report to apple but they did not answer.

i have also tried Application loader but same result.

the same questions are asked on SO, but were too old, so i have to ask a new question.

please check below screenshots.

https://postimg.org/image/4xh8kq8bt/

https://postimg.org/image/7ykey9m6p/

https://postimg.org/image/mc8g6h6pt/

Thank you.

Comment: check your email for an email from apple for removal of build.

Comment: Is your build is visible now?

Comment: Finally issue solved. The issue was that i was missing NSCalendarsUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key in info.plist file.if some one has the same problem i suggest to test the app on ios 10 device  from scratch and if some key is missing the app will crash with description in console about the missing key. Thank you every one for help and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did face the same problem. In our case we used camera, photo gallery and location but we had not added privacy key in info.plist.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow to access camera to take property images.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow to access nearest featured properties.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow to access nearest featured properties.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow to access photo library to use images.</string>
```

Another important thing is from iOS 9 iPad Multitasking support requires all the orientations but if your app does not, just add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES.

After we added above keys in application build was appearing in iTunesConnect successfully. So this might be helpful to you.

**Note :** We were getting email with error detail using which email we did uploaded application. So please check email which can help you too.

Please check following link for the list of property list required in the application.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: I did not get any mails from apple.

Comment: Did you add above keys in application? If any feature used related to privacy?

Comment: yes all the keys were already added. i think something is still missing at my end cant figure it out as apple does not provide any imformation, thats really strange.

Comment: same problem my side "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" key required or not i don't know so please give any suggestion

Comment: @PatientC hello sir same problem my project not see new version how to solve out this issue please give any suggestions &let me know how this solve this bugs step..

Comment: @RamaniHitesh Please see updated answer and you can get the list of plist properties required in the application. If you haven't added any key in the application in the application then add it which can help to you.

Comment: hello sir me add all key :1.Privacy - Calendars Usage Description
         2.Privacy - Location Always Usage Description 
         3.Privacy - Camera Usage Description
         4.Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
         5.Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
         6.Privacy - Photo Library Usage

Comment: You must getting email on developer account if build is disappearing. So please check that email in which you will have all the information why its happening. Other thing you can try is try to run application on iOS 11 so which can give you error if there is anything wrong.

Comment: no any email for developer team side , any one idea solve out this issue

Comment: how many time application upload in apps store without remove account !!, and maximum try to upload after reject apps...please help this big question mark in mind !

Comment: From my point of view there should be no limit because we should be able to update application till we have apple membership.